# Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (fossa-release X131) Instagram website doesn't work

Tags: 20.04, firefox, google-chrome, dell, instagram

I had just bought a new notebook (Dell 3050) with Ubuntu 20.04 (GNOME 3.36.8) installed.

I work with social media, and I'm having problem with Instagram: the web site just wont login. I've tried to access all my accounts (and my client's account) with no success. I've tried using Google Chrome and Firefox with no success.

Here is a print-screen with the error message: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jzFEq9nRK78bE9g-evc4Q2FCJkJMOC9Q/view
as you can see I've copied the URL at my notepad.

It's all in Portuguese, and it says to try again in a few minutes, or that my internet is not connected. I've been trying for 3 days without success.

I have no idea how to solve this, please help!!!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried translating the error messages yet?

Comment: No, how do I do that?